# replace host in url if url matches

Tags: fiddler, host

I am playing with fiddler2 "web debugger" and its working pretty fine what I wanted to do , but now I want to automate the process so I don't have to work on fiddler over and over again each time I start up the program.

what I do with fiddler :

I'm getting requests from a program (updates, news, the program traffic itself(which is needed for the program to work), and the license system)

the license system looks like that :

http://programtocrack.com/license.php?key=4294299r9&id=92492429492&time=525828552

this is the request the program makes to the server, the license.php just gives an answer OK or NO.

I've setup my own host with a plain php file which just echoes OK.

so when I change the host in the fiddler2 request to my host, the program starts up fine and works, but I need to do this every time I start up the program, I want to automate the process, I thought about the hosts file but its just for changing the whole host to another, which I can't do because the program needs to communicate with the original host after the license procedure. now I'm wondering... is there a "hosts" like file but for changing single requests like..

```
if stringtomatch ="license.php?key=*" then host = "myownhost.com"
```

so its only affecting this request, not all requests from this program?

Comment: You want to use the `AutoResponder` tab, but it sounds like what you're doing is illegal.

Comment: i've allready found that before , but i want a solution that works without fiddler. thanks anyway

Comment: I havent tried this but you should be able to redirect using host file, on windows with the url pointing to 127.0.0.1 and then the local server responding to the request.